# How would i pop and push with this priority queue?

Tags: c++, stl, typedef, priority-queue

I am trying to use the push and pop with jobs from the priority queue. How would i do this? I am curious on how to implement this?

```
class Job
    {
    public:
        int job_id;
        string job_description;
        int n_procs;    
        int n_ticks;


        Job(int job_id, string job_description, int n_procs, int n_ticks);
        Job(void);
        ~Job(void);
    };



    typedef vector<Job> Jobs;
    typedef priority_queue<Job, Jobs, less<Job>> JobQueue;
```

Comment: Have you defined `operator <` for `Job`s, or specialized `less<Job>` ?

Comment: I have not overloaded the < operator. I think the less just makes it the priority queue in decending order

Comment: @aaronaaron: How can you have a "decending order" if you don't tell C++ how to order them? Do you expect C++ to manufacture a comparison of two arbitrary objects out of whole cloth?

Comment: Are you confusing priority_queue with just a plain queue?

Comment: well i understand the priority queue...I am using it as a data structure for my assignment but i am gettin confused on how to use it with classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a lot data copy when you push a new job. keep that in mind. You have to overload the operator < for Job or specialize the template less.

Try this:

```
    class Job
{
public:
    int job_id;
    string job_description;
    int n_procs;    
    int n_ticks;


    Job(int job_id, string job_description, int n_procs, int n_ticks);
    Job(void);
    ~Job(void);
};


bool operator < (Job const& rhs, Job const& lhs)
{
    return rhs.n_ticks < lhs.n_ticks;
}

typedef vector<Job> Jobs;
typedef priority_queue<Job, Jobs, less<Job>> JobQueue;


Job job(1,"job 1", 1,2);
JobQueue jobs;

jobs.push(job);

Job const& topJop = jobs.top();
//do whatever with topTob
//remove it from the queue
job.pop();
```

Comment: is there any way i can send you my source code lol I just want you to look what i am talking about....its confusing put part of my code online

Answer (score 1):

The [priority queue class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/top/) provides basic operations for accessing elements in the queue:

- `void std::priority_queue::push(const T &)`: Pushes the given object onto the priority queue.
- `const T &std::priority_queue::top() const`: Returns the "top" element.
- `void std::priority_queue::pop();`: Removes the "top" element.

Just substitute `Job` for `T`.

BTW:

> I have not overloaded the < operator. I think the less just makes it the priority queue in decending order

And how will it know what "decending order" is without knowing how to compare them? All `std::less` does is call whatever `operator<` you have defined. If you haven't defined an `operator<`, then `std::less` will *fail* to work.

Comment: @aaronaaron: How what should look?

Answer (score 0):

refer to this reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/pop/

You find also this specification:

```
template < class T, class Container = vector<T>,
       class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> > class priority_queue;
```

That means (without trying myself) that you should be able to do:

```
JobQueue jq;
jq.push(Job(1,"one",0,1));
jq.push(Job(2,"two",2,3));
Job top = jq.pop()
```

Please look at the definition and example of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue

Comment: I saw that but i am having trouble doing with a class :(